# Dark theme not applied to all child components

Tags: vuetify.js

Looking for some suggestions. I have an app that utilizes Web Components and Vuetify. Within the parent application there is a `<v-app dark />` block that applies the dark theme to all components within the parent applications scope.

However, with the Web Components the same `<v-app dark />` block is not applied due to the shadow-dom.

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to make the web components have the same **dark** theme?

I tried wrapping each web component template in a `<v-container dark />` block but this does not set the children of the container to dark.

I can set each child component `<v-select dark />`, `<v-text-field dark />`, etc but I was hoping there might be a way to have a parent element that all children would inherit from...

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code for your app.vue file and also maybe an image of what the components look like which the dark theme isn't applying too? (I know I should be putting this as a comment instead of an answer but my rep is too low to comment).